# How to get the feeds log entry from hook_feeds_after_import

Tags: feeds

I have a feed and I want to email the log entries from feeds_log after it has completed a run. I thought that if I could get the feed_id, I could query the db to get the log entries.

I'm using `hook_feeds_after_import()`, which gives me access to the `$source` object, but in looking through some [documentation](http://labs.treehouseagency.com/feeds-docs/d0/d30/class_feeds_source.html), I don't see a way to get the feed_id.

How can I get the log entries from a feed run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `hook_feeds_after_import($source)`, I have access to `$source->imported`, which is the timestamp value in `feeds_log.request_time`. So I have

`$result = db_query('SELECT message, variables FROM {feeds_log} WHERE request_time = :imported',
    array(':imported' => $source->imported) );`

Answer (score 0):

you can always use:

```
function yourmodule_feeds_after_import(FeedsSource $source) {
  $feed_nid = $source->feed_nid;
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

If you have the module Views turned on there is a view provided by Feeds that has the path node/%nid/log where you can see the log.

If that is not what you wanted you could clone the view and adjust it to your settings.

If you want to code it instead you could always query the database. Have a look in [feeds.install](http://drupalcode.org/project/feeds.git/blob/refs/heads/7.x-2.x:/feeds.install#l225) to see what the tables are named.

Comment: Views is not a solution, I need to send out an email. Querying the database is exactly what I want to do. However I'll need to get the `feed_id`, because I don't want to email out the entire feeds history.